# Have the Tracey Ullman episodes of The Simpsons been officially released since their original air date?

Tags: distribution, the-simpsons

Around 50 one-minute shorts were produced for [The Tracey Ullman Show](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092469/) before The Simpsons got its own series. [Only the first episode has been released as a DVD extra feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Simpsons_shorts) ("[The Simpsons 138th Episode Spectacular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Simpsons_138th_Episode_Spectacular)" and "[You Kent Always Say What You Want](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Kent_Always_Say_What_You_Want)" episodes from the half-hour show additionally contain a full short).

Is the full original series available legally?

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Just as a heads-up, you don't need to worry about people linking you to unauthorised sources here - anyone doing so is violating the site rules and their answer will get deleted.

Comment: @F1Krazy: People can still give links to various streaming websites. As far as I know watching isn't illegal, uploading (and hosting if refusing to remove content) is. Additionally, I prefer official sources because quality should be held at the highest standard — no watermarks or heavy compression.

Comment: Those aren't available? That's a shame, they'd be of great interest to fans of the show. The way I remember it, the originals basically had Bart as the protagonist and Homer was just there as a really bad father to be a foil for Bart.

Comment: @T.E.D. No wonder Nancy Cartwright got exhausted...

Answer (score 14):

Based on this [Quartz article](https://qz.com/238234/heres-how-the-new-simpsons-app-will-change-your-life/), apparently an app **Simpson's World** from **FXX** should *hopefully* get all the shorts and thus will be available legally.

> Saftler said he is also working on acquiring the original Simpsons
>   shorts that aired during Fox’s The Tracey Ullman Show back in the late
>   ’80s.

But considering the article is from **2014**, there might not have been much updates on that front...

[Discussion on Reddit regarding this topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSimpsons/comments/2k5nuc/simpsons_worldin_a_nutshell/cli9urh/).

Comment: *Aww, man... sheesh!*

Comment: The Reddit thread says **The app is the FXNow app which is available now** (geo-locked to US, may require proxy or VPN outside the US)

Comment: That's why I added the Reddit thread too since I'm outside the US and can't check...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, per the Reddit thread quotes in @NikhilEshvar's answer:

**The app is the FXNow app which is available now** (geo-locked to US, may require proxy/ VPN/ etc. outside the US)

- [Android Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fxnetworks.fxnow&hl=en)
- [iTunes Store (only for iOS, not for macOS)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fxnow/id767268733?mt=8)